# How to set position of UIImageView?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage, frame

I am having an UIImageView as main view so when the main image tapped i add a subview which is another UIImageView and i would like to set the position of the ImageView of subview. Is there any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

You have to place your image like this :

```
    let yourSecondImage = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: yourMainImage.frame.origin.x + xOffset, y: yourMainImage.frame.origin.y + yOffset, width: yourImageWidth, height: yourImageHeight))
```

Then use constraints to make your subview dynamically resized

```
yourMainImage.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```